# Permissions required by Azure Service Principal to access App Insight data in a multi subscriptions AD Account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, appinsights, azure-service-principal

I have registered an Application in the Azure AD and delegated the below permissions
[image]

Now I am trying to access the App Insight data through this Azure AD App registration but I cannot get permission access for each resource group and subscriptions as doing so will be a tedious process and time taking as my organization has more than 500 subscriptions

So what are the permission that I can add to this service principal so I could access the data for all the app insight.

Answer (score 1):

To access the **App Insight data** through Azure AD App registration, please try following the below steps:

Please make note of your **AAD Tenant ID** that can be found here:

[image]

Open **PowerShell** and run as ***administrator*** and try running below cmdlets:

```
 Install-Module AzureAD
 Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <AAD Tenant ID> 
 New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId f5c26e74-f226-4ae8-85f0-b4af0080ac9e -DisplayName "Application Insights API"
```

[image]
[image]

To allow the application to access *App Insights* data:

***Go to Azure AD -> App Registrations -> Select your app -> API Permissions -> Add a permission -> Select APIs my organization uses tab -> Select Application Insights API -> Delegated Permissions -> Select Data.Read permissions -> Add Permissions***

[image]
[image]

**Note:**

- It might take up to 5 minutes for **Application Insights API** to reflect in portal.
- Try to add **Application.Read.All** and **Directory.Read.All** permissions in Microsoft Graph.
- To access this application from multiple tenants/subscriptions, make your application supported account type as **Multi-tenant** like below and **Save**:

[image]

For reference, [How to add an Azure Application Insights provider – Help US (zendesk.com)](https://squaredup1597999395.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4651613568285-How-to-add-an-Azure-Application-Insights-provider)